# How to make func.sum and group_by to output sum of the rows and merge the duplicate rows using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to generate a table which sums the number of books that are sold and the total amount paid for that distinct book in a given period of time. I need it to show a report of books that are sold.

**My subquery is:**

```
bp = db.session.query(CustomerPurchase.book_category_id, 
func.sum(CustomerPurchase.amount).label('amount'),
func.sum(CustomerPurchase.total_price).label('total_price'))\
.filter(CustomerPurchase.created_on >= start_date)\
.filter(CustomerPurchase.created_on <= end_date)\
.group_by(CustomerPurchase.book_category_id).subquery()
```

**Combined query with a subquery:**

```
cp = CustomerPurchase.query\
.join(bp, bp.c.category_id == CustomerPurchase.category_id)\
.distinct(bp.c.category_id)\
.order_by(bp.c.category_id)
```

**My CustomerPurchase table looks like this and the output of my query looks the same:**

```
id | book_category_id | book_title | amount | total_price |
---+------------------+------------+--------+-------------+
 1 |        1         | Book A     |   10   |    35.00    |
 2 |        1         | Book A     |   20   |    70.00    |
 3 |        2         | Book B     |   40   |    45.00    |
```

**Desired output after the query run should be like this:**

```
id | book_category_id | book_title | amount | total_price |
---+------------------+------------+--------+-------------+
 1 |        1         | Book A     |   30   |  105.00     |
 2 |        2         | Book B     |   40   |   45.00     |
```

Above query displays all the books that are sold to customer from CustomerPurchase table, but it doesn't `SUM` the `amount` and `total_price` nor it merges the duplicate

I have seen many examples but none of them worked for me. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a lot of research and trials I came up with a query which solved my problem. Basically I used `add_column` attribute in sqlalchemy which gave me exact rows that I wanted to display for my report.

```
bp = db.session.query(CustomerPurchase.book_store_category_id,
func.sum(CustomerPurchase.quantity).label('quantity'),
func.sum(CustomerPurchase.total_price).label('total'))\
.filter(CustomerPurchase.created_on >= start_date)\
.filter(CustomerPurchase.created_on <= end_date)

bp = bp.add_column(BookStore.book_amount)\
.filter(BookStore.category_id == CustomerPurchase.book_store_category_id)

bp = bp.add_columns(Category.category_name, Category.total_stock_amount)\
.filter(Category.id == CustomerPurchase.book_store_category_id)

bp = bp.add_column(Category.unit_cost)\
.filter(Category.id == CustomerPurchase.book_store_category_id)

bp = bp.add_column(Book.stock_amount)\
.filter(Book.category_id == CustomerPurchase.book_store_category_id)\
.group_by(BookStore.book_amount, CustomerPurchase.book_store_category_id, Category.category_name, Category.unit_cost, Category.total_stock_amount, Book.stock_amount)

bp = bp.all()
```